# how to make reactable which is reactive to data in database in R?

Tags: r, reactable

I want to display a table in shiny dashboard by using reactable. I want the data in this table change every time when there is a change in the database.
I've tried using Observe(), but when I add data in the database, the table doesn't change and still displays the previous data.

Is there a solution so that the data in the table can be as I want?

Here's the syntax I used before:

```
observe({
  output$PreviewTable <- renderReactable({
    last_data <- sqlInterpolate(con,"SELECT batch_number AS 'Batch Number'
                                     FROM production_database
                                     ORDER BY ID DESC
                                     OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;")
    last_data <- dbGetQuery(con, last_data)
    reactable(last_data)
  })
 })
```

Thankyou

Comment: An `observe` executes only when a Shiny reactive it references changes.   (And when the app starts, by default.)  Your database changes aren't Shiny reactives.  I think the only way to do what you want is to poll the database, though that *may* be highly inefficient.  One way to do that might be to add an `invalidateLater()` to your `observe`.  `invalidateLater(5000)` would poll the database every 5 seconds.  To poll the database manually, you could use an `observeEvent` linked to an `actionButton`.

Comment: There is also a function called `reactivePoll()` which can "ping" your database every x milliseconds. The cool part is that you can define a function that will fire on every interval, and the proceding reactive code will only run when that check function gives a "new/different" result, i.e you can check if the table row count has changed every 5 seconds, and if it has, the table will update.

Comment: The check function should be a sql query that gives you the row count of your desired table. If your table(s) is(are) very large most row count queries will be slow. However, if you are using MSSQL, the row count can be quickly queried if you use `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` table. Tell me if you need a example.